# How can I add different level of audio decibel(dB) noise to the original audio signal using python?

Tags: python, audio

> I have audio data without noise.

```
data = read_audio_file("input_data/AGS00/VM0MAGS00S1R1F00.wav")
```

> I want to add noise with this data and the noise level is 60db. I used numpy to add noise but I don't know exactly how to add **60db** noise.

```
  def add_noise(data):
        noise = np.random.randn(len(data))
        data_noise = data + 0.005 * noise
        return data_noise
```